# C# Generate client Certificate from Root Certificate using CertEnroll

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, self-signed-certificate, certenroll, root-certificate

I would like to write a function that generates client certificates signed by my root certificate using CertEnroll.dll,
I do have Root PFX file at specific location and by reading that creating CSignerCertificate object.
Here is my code for the same.

I am getting error for below code 'CertEnroll::CSignerCertificate::Initialize: Cannot find object or property. 0x80092004 (-2146885628 CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND)'

```
 public static X509Certificate2 CertCreateNew(string subjectName)
    {
        // create DN for subject and issuer
        var dn = new CX500DistinguishedName();
        dn.Encode("CN=" + subjectName, X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE);


        // create a new private key for the certificate
        CX509PrivateKey privateKey = new CX509PrivateKey();
        privateKey.ProviderName = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0";
        privateKey.MachineContext = false;
        privateKey.Length = 2048;
        privateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_SIGNATURE; // use is not limited
        privateKey.ExportPolicy = X509PrivateKeyExportFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG;
        privateKey.Create();


        var hashobj = new CObjectId();
        hashobj.InitializeFromAlgorithmName(ObjectIdGroupId.XCN_CRYPT_HASH_ALG_OID_GROUP_ID,
            ObjectIdPublicKeyFlags.XCN_CRYPT_OID_INFO_PUBKEY_ANY,
            AlgorithmFlags.AlgorithmFlagsNone, "SHA256");

        // add extended key usage if you want - look at MSDN for a list of possible OIDs
        var oid = new CObjectId();
        oid.InitializeFromValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"); // SSL server
        var oidlist = new CObjectIds();
        oidlist.Add(oid);
        var eku = new CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage();
        eku.InitializeEncode(oidlist);

        // Create the self signing request
        var cert = new CX509CertificateRequestCertificate();
        X509Certificate2 signercertificate = CertOpen("My Personal CA");
        X509Certificate2 signer = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\\PKICertificates\\Root Certificates\\MyPersonalCA.pfx"), "password");
        if (signer == null)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Signer not found");
        }            

        ISignerCertificate signerCertificate = new CSignerCertificate();

        signerCertificate.Initialize(false, X509PrivateKeyVerify.VerifySilent, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, Convert.ToBase64String(signer.RawData)); 

        cert.Issuer.Encode(signer.Subject, X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE);

        cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, privateKey, "");           
        cert.SignerCertificate = (CSignerCertificate)signerCertificate;
        cert.Subject = dn;            
        cert.NotBefore = DateTime.Now;
        // this cert expires immediately. Change to whatever makes sense for you
        cert.NotAfter = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10);
        cert.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)eku); // add the EKU
        cert.HashAlgorithm = hashobj; // Specify the hashing algorithm
        cert.Encode(); // encode the certificate

        // Do the final enrollment process
        var enroll = new CX509Enrollment();
        enroll.InitializeFromRequest(cert); // load the certificate
        enroll.CertificateFriendlyName = subjectName; // Optional: add a friendly name

        string csr = enroll.CreateRequest(); // Output the request in base64
                                             // and install it back as the response
        enroll.InstallResponse(InstallResponseRestrictionFlags.AllowUntrustedCertificate,
            csr, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, ""); // no password
                                                            // output a base64 encoded PKCS#12 so we can import it back to the .Net security classes
        var base64encoded = enroll.CreatePFX("", // no password, this is for internal consumption
            PFXExportOptions.PFXExportChainWithRoot);

        // instantiate the target class with the PKCS#12 data (and the empty password)
        return new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(
            System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64encoded), "",
            // mark the private key as exportable (this is usually what you want to do)
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable
        );
    }
```

Does anyone know how I can generate a client CX509CertificateRequest signed by my root?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468304/exception-on-attempt-to-create-not-self-signed-certificate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception on attempt to create not self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468304/exception-on-attempt-to-create-not-self-signed-certificate)

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer by doing trial and error and finally got success. Posting code here may be it will helpful to others who are getting same error.

Note: No need to assign Issuer property it will set automatically, if IssuerCertificate property is assigned before Encode

```
public static X509Certificate2 CertCreateNew(string subjectName)
    {
        X509Certificate2 signer = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\\PKICertificates\\Root Certificates\\MyPersonalCA.pfx"), "password");

        // create DN for subject and issuer
        var dn = new CX500DistinguishedName();
        dn.Encode("CN=" + subjectName, X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE);


        // create a new private key for the certificate
        CX509PrivateKey privateKey = new CX509PrivateKey();
        privateKey.ProviderName = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0";
        privateKey.MachineContext = false;
        privateKey.Length = 2048;
        privateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_SIGNATURE; // use is not limited
        privateKey.ExportPolicy = X509PrivateKeyExportFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG;
        privateKey.Create();


        var hashobj = new CObjectId();
        hashobj.InitializeFromAlgorithmName(ObjectIdGroupId.XCN_CRYPT_HASH_ALG_OID_GROUP_ID,
            ObjectIdPublicKeyFlags.XCN_CRYPT_OID_INFO_PUBKEY_ANY,
            AlgorithmFlags.AlgorithmFlagsNone, "SHA256");

        // add extended key usage if you want - look at MSDN for a list of possible OIDs
        var oid = new CObjectId();
        oid.InitializeFromValue("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2"); // SSL server
        var oidlist = new CObjectIds();
        oidlist.Add(oid);
        var eku = new CX509ExtensionEnhancedKeyUsage();
        eku.InitializeEncode(oidlist);

        // Create the self signing request
        var cert = new CX509CertificateRequestCertificate();
        if (signer == null)
            throw new CryptographicException("Signer not found");


        ISignerCertificate signerCertificate = new CSignerCertificate();
        signerCertificate.Initialize(false, X509PrivateKeyVerify.VerifySilent, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, Convert.ToBase64String(signer.RawData));


        cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextUser, privateKey, "");
        cert.SignerCertificate = (CSignerCertificate)signerCertificate;
        cert.Subject = dn;
        cert.NotBefore = DateTime.Now.Date;
        cert.NotAfter = cert.NotBefore + new TimeSpan(3650, 0, 0, 0);
        cert.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)eku); // add the EKU
        cert.HashAlgorithm = hashobj; // Specify the hashing algorithm
        cert.Encode(); // encode the certificate

        // Do the final enrollment process
        var enroll = new CX509Enrollment();
        enroll.InitializeFromRequest(cert); // load the certificate
        enroll.CertificateFriendlyName = subjectName; // Optional: add a friendly name

        string csr = enroll.CreateRequest();
        enroll.InstallResponse(InstallResponseRestrictionFlags.AllowUntrustedCertificate,
            csr, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, "");
        var base64encoded = enroll.CreatePFX("", // no password, this is for internal consumption
            PFXExportOptions.PFXExportChainWithRoot);

        // instantiate the target class with the PKCS#12 data (and the empty password)
        return new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(
            System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64encoded), "",
            // mark the private key as exportable (this is usually what you want to do)
            System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable
        );
    }
```